# Get-Content command not recongized when executed through script in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm getting this exception when I try to run the command using c# code on the server:

> The term 'Get-Content' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

If I open Windows PowerShell on server and run this `Get-Content` command it  is executed successfully.

`Get-Content -Path "pathtofile" -Encoding byte -ReadCount 0`

Anyone have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: PowerShell opened from Start menu has different profile. You have to load all required modules manually.

Comment: How are you executing the command in C#?  Ideally you should use the [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0) rather than trying to call 'PowerShell.exe'

Comment: I'm creating pipline using runspace and invoking the command using c#

Answer (score 0):

You are using another profile maybe.

try this:

```
PS /home/.../temp> Get-Command Get-Content                                      

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Content                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

From there you can see where the command is being executed, so you can simply do

```
PS /home/....temp> Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management -Force -Verbose
```